# Swift Decode JSON - can not decode

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I can not decode my JSON File. It works if I decode only a single string but now with my struct it does not work. Is there anything that I do wrong?

My struct that i want to decode:

```
struct Comment: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var comments : [String]

    private enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
        case commentsArray = "commentsArray"
        case title = "title"
        case comments = "comments"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        let response = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Keys.self, forKey: .response)
        let commentsArray = try response.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Keys.self, forKey: .commentsArray)
        title = try commentsArray.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)!
        comments = try commentsArray.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .comments)!
    }
}
```

My JSON:

```
{"Response": {
    "commentsArray":[
      {
        "title": "someTitle",
        "comments": [
          "optionOne",
          "optionTwo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "title",
        "comments": [
          "optionOne",
          "optionTwo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "someto",
        "comments": [
          "optionOne",
          "optionTwo"
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

use these structs to decode your json

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var response : Comments

    private enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
      case response = "Response"
    }
}
struct Comments: Codable {
    var commentsArray : [comment]
}
struct comment: Codable {
    let title: String
    let comments: [String]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you want to structure your code this way. You have a hierarchy that you are attempting to capture in a flatter structure.

```
Response
    CommentsList
        Comments
            Title
            Comment
            Comment
            ...
        Comments
        ...
```

So, you might want to do something like this:

```swift
struct Response: Decodable {
    var commentsArray: [Comments]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: ResponseCodingKeys.self)
        let response = try! container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ListCodingKeys.self, forKey: .response)
        commentsArray = try! response.decode([Comments].self, forKey: .commentsArray)
    }

    enum ResponseCodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case response = "Response" }
    enum ListCodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case commentsArray }
}

struct Comments: Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var comments: [String]
}
```